# how can I create a button with texturepackerimporter texture?

Tags: unity-game-engine, uibutton, texturepacker

I can drag the prefabs texture to scene. But I don't know how to create a ui button use this texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need TexturePacker to create a button. Unity has a SpritePacker that handles all the texture packing.

To create a button select GameObject > UI > Button and in the Inspector View drag in your texture.

And take a look at this Introduction Tutorial from Unity:
http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-button